# C++ using && with your class without bool/&& overload?

Tags: c++

I was told that you can in fact do `MyClass a, b; ... if (a && b) {...}` without 1) overloading the && operator 2) overloading the bool operator (ex: `class MyClass { ... operator bool(){return boolval; } };`)

The solution was to use a pointer-to-member-function. I did not understand how to use this solution. My notes say the below but i couldn't get more then that. Does anyone know how to do this?

> the function takes a private nested
>   struct as a parameter. The reason is
>   that that type can’t legally be
>   converted into anything else – it can
>   never be used in any expression other
>   than a Boolean context

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Note: Typically answers to* `[homework]` *questions do not immediately give away the solution. However, according to your question you already know the solution but don't understand it. I'll attempt to explain.*

From the information you provided in your question, your instructor was probably talking about some variant of the [safe bool idiom](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool.html):

```
class MyClass
{
private:
    typedef void (MyClass::*SafeBoolType)() const;
    void ThisTypeDoesNotSupportComparisons() const {}
public:
    operator SafeBoolType() const {
        // The actual conditional expression would go where "true" is.
        //      ____
        //     |    |
        return (true) ? &MyClass::ThisTypeDoesNotSupportComparisons : 0;
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyClass a;
    MyClass b;

    if(a && b) {}      // Compiles.
    /* if(a < b) {} */ // Doesn't compile.
}
```

Here, we provide a type cast operator to a pointer-to-member-function, which can only be used in boolean contexts. This allows the `if` statement with the logical operator (`&&`) to compile even without a `bool` typecast or an `&&` operator overload. It also prevents the `if` statement with the comparison operator (`<`) from compiling.

However, I don't understand the part in your notes that mentions "the function takes a private nested struct as a parameter". The safe bool idiom doesn't require that the member function take an unnamed `struct`. I suggest that you ask your instructor; it is possible that I have completely misunderstood the problem.

Comment: The link you provided shows an example with a `private nested struct` and after reading through it, i am 100% sure this technique is what he meant. +1 and accept